# Are user agent names case-sensitive in robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, user-agent, case-sensitive

I'm blocking various bots in robots.txt and I was wondering if their names are case-sensitive.

For example:

```
User-agent: grapeshot
Disallow: /
```

Would it matter if I use `grapeshot` or `GrapeShot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bot names are not case sensitive. However, the filepaths **are** case sensitive.

Please refer to [Google’s *Robots.txt Specifications*](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) document.